# Laravel 5.2 create web service

Tags: php, android, web-services, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I'd like to create a new web-service under laravel controlling environment. 
is is applicable in laravel? or I need to build a normal web-service with php and connect it to my laravel app?

The target for building this web-service to work with Android and IOS Apps.
I searched at [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2) but I found nothing related to web-service

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lumen or laravel framework for develop web services

`Lumen` is a `“micro-framework`” built on top of Laravel’s components created by Taylor Otwell who is also responsible for Laravel.

> It has been designed to develop micro services like small application
>   or web service. It has been developed for speed. In Lumen Symfony’s
>   Routing component which has been used by Laravel replaced by FastRoute
>   to enhance performance.

more details

https://coderexample.com/restful-api-in-lumen-a-laravel-micro-framework/